# jQuery - Using replaceWith twice doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to replace a HTML element with another element. It works great the first time, but not the second time. I have no idea why it doesn't work the second time.

Anyone any idea?

Here's an example of the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/jfYLG/

---

The code from the jsfiddle example:

```
<div class="blaat">
    <div>woot</div>
</div>

<button class="work" type="button">Work</button>

$(function() {
    $clone = $('.blaat').clone().addClass('test');

    $('.work').click(function() {
        $('.blaat').replaceWith($clone);
    });
});
```

Comment: Try: `$clone = $('.blaat').clone( true ).addClass('test')`

Comment: Looks like your code is working fine. Just add attributes to the class and you can see the difference

  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/jfYLG/2/

Comment: @Sushanth-- It disappears the second time.  The user's problem was it wasn't 'working' the second time, so I would stand to agree that it is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('.work').click(function() {
        $clone = $('.blaat').clone().addClass('test');
        $('.blaat').replaceWith($clone);
    });
});
```

Comment: lol, i find it strange that i have to 're-clone' it. I thought that having one copy in "memory" would be good enough to re-use over and over. Obviously that's not the case... In any way, your solution works great :)